# How to save multiple users data in the cookies using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-hooks

*Hello there!*

i have one page that have one form in it,

this form have one button for submit and two inputs : one for username and the other for password

i want to save username and password in Cookies after each time i pressed the button
and i want the cookies remember the previous user data (username,password)

for example the cookies should have data like this :

> 1st user {username:"user",passord:"pw"}
> 2end user{username:"user2",passord:"pw2"}

add goes on

i try the useCookies hook

```
const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies([]);
```

when i pressed the button this code get executed :

```
  setCookie('username', username, { path: '/' });
  setCookie('password', pw, { path: '/' });
```

but after each press the previous user data get deleted from the cookies and the cookies anly have the last user data

if you know how to let the cookies save all the users data please tell me.
thnks for your time

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set the cookies you'll be using in the dependency array of the `useCookie` hook:

```js
const [cookies, setCookies] = useCookies(["username", "password"]);
```

Then you can read the cookie each time you submit a new user and add it to an array, and store the result in the cookie:

```
const setUserCookie = (username) => {
  const previousUsers = cookies["username"] || [];
  const newUsers = [...previousUsers, username];
    
  setCookies("username", newUsers, { path: "/" }); // ['user1', 'user2']
};
```

To make working with the data a little easier you could put the username and password in an object, and store these records in a single cookie:

```
const userToAdd = { name: username, password: pw };
const previousUsers = cookies["users"] || [];
const newUsers = [...previousUsers, userToAdd];

setCookies("users", newUsers, { path: "/" }); // { name: 'user1', password: 'foo' }
```